# If $f$ is invertible in $A \subset M$, $\lim_n \sum_{x \in f^{-1}(y)} g_n (y) = \chi_{f(A)}(y)$?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, characteristic-functions

If $f$ is invertible in $A \subset M$, $M$ compact metric space, and $(g_n)_n$ is a sequence of continuous functions converging to $\chi_A$, with $\sup|g_n| \leq \sup \chi_A = 1 $ then

$\lim_n \sum_{x \in f^{-1}(y)} g_n (y) = \chi_{f(A)}(y)$.

I could not do it, any suggestions? I think it is necessary that $f(A) \subset A$.

Comment: $\chi_A$ is an indicator of A, am I right?

Comment: yes, that's right

Comment: $f(A)\subset A$ is not possible unless $M\subset\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Also, I'm confused about your symbols. In $\sum\limits_{x\in f^{-1}(y)}$ you mean that you are summing over all possible $x\in f^{-1}(\{y\})$. If so, why is there no $x$ in the sum?

Comment: @ΒασίληςΜάρκος that's right. The sum is over all $x \in f^{-1}(\{ y \})$, but the expression is in agreement with the book. I also think this is confusing

Comment: Possibly it just means $\sum_{x \in f^{-1}(y)} g_n (y) = | f^{-1}(y)|g_n(y)$ (i.e., the cardinality of $f^{-1}(y)$). But this would only work if $f^{-1}(y)$ is always finite, which your conditions do not require for $y \notin f(A)$. So either that is an erroneous notation, or there are conditions on $f$ that you haven't given, or else the result is false. If $f^{-1}(y)$ is always finite, then the result can be shown without any reference to the topology of $M$ or continuity of $g_n$.